# Persist the (Set Cookie) JSESSIONID throughout a TestPlan in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, setcookie, jsessionid

I have to test the webserver which has to maintain sessions. For this purpose I need to maintain session ids in jmeter. It has been working for ThreadGroup as I am using HTTP Cookie Manager for every Thread Group.
But i want to use the same **JSESSIONID** across the test plan which includes several Thread Groups. Not able to achieve this. I tried using HTTP Cookie Manager globally for a Test Plan, but it didnt work.

I am using jmeter 2.5 version.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this in the current 2.9 release, it seems to have been improved a lot.